# Tosca run Testcase for every row in TDS/TDM

Tags: tosca

I finished my Testcase and now, I want to test my process with different data.
I already made a Table/Type with the necessary attributes and entries I need in the Test Data Management. (on the Website)
And I also know, that I get the data of the first row, when I say: {TD[Item.Attribute]}
(The item is the Table or the Type)
But I want the TestCase to run once for every row and not just for the first. But I do not know how to do that.

I know how the Instanciate a TestCase Template with the TestCaseDesign. But how do I do it with the TestCaseService/Management?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a while loop. You need to have an attribute added to the table to indicate if an entry is already processed or not, for e.g. Attribute named 'Processed' having initial value as 'No' for every row in the TDM.
Then create a while loop and in the condition of loop search for TDM table entry where attribute Processed has value No.
In the loop part, add the test case steps to be executed. After the end of execution for every row of data, update Attribute 'Processed' value to 'Yes' so that it doesnt get picked up in the next run of the while loop.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).